Cannot align button in the center using Bootstrap 5 and Flexbox
I am trying to align the Define New a tag in the center but cannot understand what am I doing wrong. I am new to this concept, so please bear with me.
Here is the code
<div class="col-xl-3 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
                              <div>
                                <div class="panel-body d-flex flex-column justify-content-start">
                                  <div  class="pb-6 align-items-center">
                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-success" (click)="newContactPerson()">Define
                                      New</a>
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="support-sidebar">
                                    <ul class="side-menu">
                                      <li *ngFor="let contactPerson of contactPersonItems; let i = index"
                                      >
                                        <div>
                                          <a class="side-menu__item contact-person-item"
                                             (click)="selectContactPerson(i)"
                                             [class.active]="activeContactPersonIndex === i">
                                            <i class="fe fe-user side-menu__icon me-2 text-success"
                                               [class.text-success]="contactPerson.isDefault"></i>
                                            <span
                                              class="side-menu__label">{{ contactPerson.firstName + " " + contactPerson.lastName }}</span>
                                            <i class="fe fe-trash-2 delete-icon" (click)="deleteContactPerson(i)"></i>
                                          </a>
                                        </div>

                                      </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <div *ngIf="contactPersonItems.length == 0">No data available</div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-light btn-block text-primary mt-5"
                                   (click)="setDefault()">Set Default</a>
                              </div>
                            </div>



see: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

You need add text-center in your div
<div  class="pb-6 align-items-center text-center">
  <a class="btn btn-success">..</a>
</div>

Try to explain. the outer div has flex flex-column, the align-items-center makes that the div is vertically centered, but not related to center horizontally.
To know about flex, I love this link. The bootstrap utilities about flex only reply the flex concepts.
